# android ImageView from different thread going very slow

Tags: android, multithreading

I am currently decoding the encoded frame coming from remote server. Now I have some different threads. One thread is for receive, one is for decode and another is for View. All these are created from activity class(main thread). Now I send a object of the parent class to the Viewer class for accessing ImageView. In that ImageView I just write the following snippet.

```
m_ImageView.post(new Runnable() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        m_ImageView.setImageBitmap(m_bImage);
        m_iDecompressedImage = null;
    }
});
```

Here m_ImageView is the ImageView and m_bImage is the Bitmap Image. But there is an issue of performance. Here The Viewer thread is very slow. I don’t know the other efficient way to do my job. Please give me some light.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the concept of [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) which could help u in all manner...

Answer (score 0):

Have one background thread that receives the image from the server and decodes make sure to use appropriate sampling for speed and memory efficiency if necessary.

Store the `Bitmap` in some cache, maybe [`LruCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html), use a `Handler.Callback` that handles messages when the image is downloaded successfully or fails. Initialize a `Handler` on the UI thread with that `Handler.Callback` and send messages to it from the background thread when decoding is completed and the image is stored.

This is only the gist of the method of course, if you are not interested you can just plug in a developed library for this for lazy loading images.

Comment: Thank you for Replying. Now My question, is UI thread is necessary to be implemented in main activity class/thread?

Comment: The UI thread is the main thread, it does not need to be started, it handles events from the user and that's where you modify `View`s.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Your guidance told me that I have to use ImageView in main thread. That means a handler from Decoder thread will notify the main thread to update the UI thread providing the current Bitmap.

Comment: Make sure to initiate the `Handler` on the main thread and tag it as `final` and you can use it in the background thread. Otherwise you will need to pass it the `Looper` from the main thread if you want to initiate it in the background thread.